# jquery.on scroll doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a DOM event recorder so I can play back how a user interacted with a page.  I would like to use the jquery.on functionality so I can record all events on page.  In this particular instance I am trying to record scroll events but eventually I want to record all sorts of events.

Here is a link to my JS Fiddle.  I expect the text "Hello" to change to "Bye" after a user scrolls the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/MnpPM/

Herel is the html

```
<div id="parent" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; overflow: scroll">
    <div style="height: 500px; width: 500px">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

and here the javascript

```
$(document).on('scroll', '*', function () { $(this).html('Bye') });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `scroll` event does not propagate through dom, so you can't use with delegate.

if you want to listen to the `scroll` event you need to add the callback direct to the element:

```
$(function() {
     $("#parent").on('scroll', function () { $(this).html('Bye') });
});
```

Comment: Does that mean what I want to do is not possible?  Can you suggest any way to record all scroll events?

Comment: @RyanFishman not with a delegate. you need to add you scroll callbacks directly to all elements that are scrollable yourself (which is really annoying). if you have much dynamic content, you could think of using a class `scrollable` for all this element, to make it easier to find them.

Comment: Ok, the problem is I would like to inject this library into unknown pages as a recording API.  I would like to for them just to add this on their page without them needing to change the HTML or CSS or Javascript.

Comment: @RyanFishman well there is probably a workaround, but i haven't tested and it won't work for all situations (e.g. scrolling with touch devices or by keyboard) but you could try using the mouseenter and mouseleave events to register/unregister the scroll events to the scrollable parents. And for touch there is probably a similar way. But as i said it is just an idea, i haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

As t.niese said, using mouseenter and mouseleave might be an option for you or anybody with similar requirements, i modified the jsfiddle code, so it might give a hint to who ever is reading, be aware that is buggy but you get the point.

http://jsfiddle.net/MnpPM/30/

Here is the code:

```
var scrollCount = 0;
$('body').on('mouseenter','*',function(e){
    console.log('mouseenter');
    $(this).scroll(function(){
           scrollCount++;
           console.log('Current Count:'+scrollCount);
    });   
    $(this).mouseout(function() {
      $(this).unbind();
    }); 
});
```

I used a similar code for a scrolling div that was loaded dynamically and it worked.

Comment: Nice workaround... it's not awesome to do to every element but it works for elements loaded into the DOM after the initial JS has been parsed so you don't have to set new events on each call.