# Javascript listeners to Divs that will be attached AFTER document is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listener, document-ready

I am trying to put a listener to a scrollable div that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $scroll = $('.generic-table')
        $scroll.scroll(function() {
           // if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
               alert("bottom!");
           // }
        });
});
```

The problem is that this **Div** is not part of the original template but it is added to the template **AFTER** the user takes a specific action.

If the **Div** was loaded in the beginning of the page, it would work.

How to overcome that kind of issue?

Comment: Move the code out of .ready and in to wherever adds the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use event delegation for `.scroll()` as @marcelosalloum rightly pointed out in the comments. You have to write the handler when you actually create the element.

```
//Create .generic-table here. BEGIN
Code
//Create .generic-table here. END

//Handle event immediately.
$('.generic-table').scroll(function() {
    alert("bottom!");
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this is an example of event delegation. You are placing an event on the document to listen for any scroll events. And then running the callback only if the event target is `.generic-table`

Comment: According to [t.niese](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609120/jquery-on-scroll-doesnt-work?answertab=votes#answer-14609160) scroll events do not propagate through DOM, so one can't use it with delegate.

Comment: @marcelosalloum - you're right. it won't. updating my answer.