# Javascript Event Handlers on elements appended after document is ready

Tags: javascript, html, dom, delegates, scroll

I have a javasript function that should change the value of an element appended after document is ready. 
What I mean is: If the javascript appends a div like: `<div class="new-div"></div>`, I cannot intercept actions on that DIV.

This code does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.new-div').on('click', function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

But this code, using delegate, works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.author-profile-articles-table', function(){
                alert('clicked');
            });
});
```

However, when the scroll event is needed, the following code does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('scroll', '.author-profile-articles-table', function(){
        alert('scrolled');
    });
});
```

According to [t.niese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609120/jquery-on-scroll-doesnt-work?answertab=votes#answer-14609160), scroll events do not propagate through DOM, so one can't use it with delegate to make this work.

Script tags along with the html do work but I don't feel it is an elegant/smart way.

The question is, if a scroll intercepter does not work with DOM, is that a way to put the event interceptors from a separate javascript file or the html script tag is the only option?

Cheers,

Comment: Can you provide a full example- i.e. when are you appending the div with the class '.new-div' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work using the bind tag:

When I finished performing a given action, a trigger an event using:

```
$.trigger('eventName');
```

Than I build the event listener using bind:

```
$(document).bind('eventName', function(){
    // Do your stuff here.
}
```

It works smoothly =)